# React unmount component which has been rendered like that: <MyComponent/>

Tags: reactjs

I know this method:

```
React.render(<Account/>, document.getElementById('app'));
React.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('app'));
```

But what if my component has been rendered like that ?

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <MyComponent/>
    </div>
</body>
```

Rendering function of MyComponent:

```
 render: function() {
       <div id=search>
           <input etc........./> 
       </div>
   }
```

I tried

```
React.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('search'));
```

and

```
React.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('container'));
```

but it's not working.

What should I do ?

Comment: This question is very unclear - what are you actually trying to unmount? `Account`, `app` or `MyComponent`? Unmounting works flawlessly it's just that React can't find your component at your selectors. Working example here http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/11059/

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227792/react-js-removing-a-component is the answer you are looking for

Comment: I try to unmount mycomponent

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to unmount it? Have you considered changing the `render` function of its parent to render it conditionally?