# how to remove / unmount nested react components

Tags: reactjs-flux, reactjs

I'd like to unmount a single react component, which belongs to a parent component containing three components total. The parent component has this render function:

```
render: function () {
  return (
    <div className={classes}>
      <Navbar ref="navbar"/>
      <Home ref="home"/>
      <Footer ref="footer"/>
    </div>
),

handleNavbarClick: function () {
  // remove Home
}
```

if a user then clicks on a link in the navbar and I want to unmount the Home component, how would I do that? it seems like my only option is to do something like this (taken from [react.js: removing a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227792/react-js-removing-a-component)), but this seems pretty gross:

```
render: function () {
  var home = this.state.remove_home ? null : <Home ref="home />
  return (
    <div className={classes}>
      <Navbar ref="navbar"/>
      {home}
      <Footer ref="footer"/>
    </div>
),

handleNavbarClick: function () {
  this.setState({remove_home: true});
}
```

Is that the appropriate react way to do things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your proposed solution of

```javascript
render: function () {
  var home = this.state.remove_home ? null : <Home ref="home" />
  return (
    <div className={classes}>
      <Navbar ref="navbar"/>
      {home}
      <Footer ref="footer"/>
    </div>
),

handleNavbarClick: function () {
  this.setState({remove_home: true});
}
```

is more-or-less the "correct" way to handle this with React. Remember, the purpose of `render` is to describe the way your component should look *at any given point*. Reaching out to the DOM and performing manual operations, or doing other kind of imperative work like "removing" an element, is almost always the wrong thing to do.

If you're concerned about the syntax, you can consider inlining or extracting the logic:

```javascript
render: function () {
  return (
    <div className={classes}>
      <Navbar ref="navbar"/>
      {this.state.remove_home ? null : <Home ref="home" />}
      <Footer ref="footer"/>
    </div>
),
```

or

```javascript
render: function () {
  return (
    <div className={classes}>
      <Navbar ref="navbar"/>
      {!this.state.remove_home && <Home ref="home" />}
      <Footer ref="footer"/>
    </div>
),
```

or

```javascript
render: function () {
  return (
    <div className={classes}>
      <Navbar ref="navbar"/>
      {this.renderHome()}
      <Footer ref="footer"/>
    </div>
),

renderHome: function() {
  if (!this.state.remove_home) {
    <Home ref="home" />
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I like the idea of breaking out renderHome into its own function

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
handleNavBarClick: function(){
    React.findDOMNode(this.refs.home).style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: mmm yeah that would work except the component's listeners would remain intact.